# How to add Windows Form to web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio

I am new to .NET so I have a basic question to ask, is there a way to add Windows Forms application to my web page, as creating forms was easy and I created my app in the form format now I want to add them to asp.net page.

Comment: Maybe its the time to search for the difference between win apps and web apps, try this : https://www.google.ae/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=deference+between+windows+app+and+web+app#hl=en&sa=X&ei=mB6qT-_rMMrtrQfd1_zrAQ&ved=0CBkQvwUoAQ&q=difference+between+windows+app+and+web+app&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=89f566654526bacd&biw=1366&bih=653

Comment: Why the downvotes? The question is valid even if it's naive.

Comment: What is your objective or any specific reason that you trying something like this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Form Application Inside An ASP.NET Page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625794/windows-form-application-inside-an-asp-net-page)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty:- i am good with forms as compared to asp.net hence i thought I can i might be able to incorporate my forms in my webpage thats it..

Comment: @user1374181: If it was your idea behind that, I think the best way is to polish your skills in web forms rather than stuck in here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a different thing, but you might want to look into the silverlight out-of-browser technology.

http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/out-of-browser-applications/out-of-browser-applications-(silverlight-quickstart)

Comment: he doesn't even know the concept of HTML forms and you are dragging him to Silverlight!!!

Comment: Since he has much to learn, he migth as well start with something that is closer to what he wishes for :-)

Comment: HTML forms and SL are pretty much mutally exclusive, so no, he doesn't really need to know HTML if he intends to do SL.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comment, just check out the link :- http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Place-Windows-Control-To-Web-Form.aspx  this is what i am trying to do but unable to do so, I think I should go through asp.net forms deeply...

Answer (score 1):

Spend good time on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com) learning about `<form>` tags..
then gradually move on towards processing data at backend using C#
a good starting point can be http://www.deitel.com/articles/csharp_tutorials/20060128/index.html

Long way to go..first get your basics right!!

Answer (score 0):

Windows form cannot be added in a web form. They altogether are a different technology. You can add link in your web app for downloading Windows app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have basic knowledge of html, then you can learn the [basics](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp) of asp.net too. Then you can easily create a web form which exactly matches your windows forms. But always keep it in mind, webforms are not as flexible as windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

well... there are something you can do that is similar.

You can add your windows-form to an BHO and install it in you webBrowser as an ActiveX object (for a IE) or extension (in other browsers), and then share it to everyone you want. Then your win-form application can start and interact with your web-page.
You can start looking here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436(v=vs.85).aspx

hope it help.